Removing AMP: which status code?
I relate on this Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/amp/remove-amp
It states,

Configure your server to return either an HTTP 301 Moved Permanently
or 302 Found response for the removed AMP page.

My big question: why Google recommends 302? Is it not always the best case to go with 301?

It all depends on your future plans. When you throw a 302 redirect, you can rebuild the page in the future.
Or, for example, you just want to test the impact of removing amp page on the domain.
That is, the page ranking for the search engine does not change and is not transferred to the new url.
At least that's what Google says.
